# Proof double covering of $SO(V,Q)$ by $Spin(V,Q)$ is local homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces, spin-geometry

Let $(V,Q)$ be a finite-dimensional quadratic space over either the real or complex numbers with a non-degenerate, but not necessarily positive-definite quadratic form $Q$.
We define the Spin group $Spin(V,Q)$ as $Pin(V,Q) \cap Cl_0(V,Q)$, meaning as the subset of the Clifford algebra which is generated by an even number of elements $v \in V$ with $Q(v) = \pm 1$.

It is easy to prove that $$ 0 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to Spin(V,Q) \stackrel{Ad}\to SO(V,Q) \to 0$$ is exact, so all that remains to be proved for the adjoint representation $Ad$ to be a covering map is that it is a local homeomorphism.

We can equip both $Spin(V,Q)$ and $SO(V,Q)$ with the subspace topology induced by a norm of our choosing on $Cl(V,Q)$ and $GL(V)$, respectively. These are finite-dimensional vector spaces, so all norms induce the same topology.

Now, I do not quite know how to proceed. Could someone either point me to sources which prove that $Ad$ is a local homeomorphism or prove it themselves?

Comment: Spin(V) and SO(V) have a natural compact Lie group structure (the former induced by the Clifford Algebra). So it's easy to check that $Ad$ is a Lie group map with finite kernel. Thus it is a covering map, this is proved in general, for example in Warner's "Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups"

Comment: @FedericoT. , thanks a lot for your quick reply! I now understand why Ad is a Lie group map. However, I could not find the proof you are referring to in Warner's book. Could you perhaps point me to the exact page?

Comment: Use proposition 3.26 plus the fact that the tangent space of the kernel at the identity coincides with the kernel of the pushforward map induced on the corresponding Lie Algebras